# How to insert an HTML table into a WebBrowser control C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, browser, html-table

I am using the .NET WebBrowser control to as a WYSIWYG html editor.  I've been using the ExecCommand to do the formatting function fine so far, however I now want to add a table inserter.  The problem is I can only seem to Append the table to the document, not insert it half way through.  Below is some basic test code, if anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

```
        HtmlElement tableRow = null;
        HtmlElement headerElem = null;

        HtmlDocument doc = wbDesign.Document;
        HtmlElement tableElem = doc.CreateElement("TABLE");
        doc.Body.AppendChild(tableElem);

        HtmlElement tableHeader = doc.CreateElement("THEAD");
        tableElem.AppendChild(tableHeader);
        tableRow = doc.CreateElement("TR");
        tableHeader.AppendChild(tableRow);
        headerElem = doc.CreateElement("TH");
        headerElem.InnerText = "Col1";
        tableRow.AppendChild(headerElem);

        headerElem = doc.CreateElement("TH");
        headerElem.InnerText = "Col2";
        tableRow.AppendChild(headerElem);

        HtmlElement tableBody = doc.CreateElement("TBODY");
        tableElem.AppendChild(tableBody);

        tableRow = doc.CreateElement("TR");
        tableBody.AppendChild(tableRow);
        HtmlElement tableCell = doc.CreateElement("TD");
        tableCell.InnerText = "Test";
        tableRow.AppendChild(tableCell);
        tableCell = doc.CreateElement("TD");
        tableCell.InnerText = "Test";
        tableRow.AppendChild(tableCell);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate the HtmlDocument structure, finding the node at where you want to insert it, and then append there. If you Append to the Body, you'll just add to the end of the last element, i.e. the end.

Comment: Any idea how you do this based on the current selection?

Comment: you need help finding the last element in the control range of IHTMLDocument2::selection ? it has a length property.

Comment: The problem I have is i cannot seem to insert the table into the current selection?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late - but I recently had this requirment and came up with this. I've tried to make this a minimal as possible, to show the methodology, and allow you to customise this a required.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;

public class HtmlToWebBrowserControlDoc
{

    // The loaded document MUST have a script similar to this

    //      <script type="text/javascript" >
    //              function appendHtml(o) {
    //              var div = document.createElement("div");
    //              div.innerHTML = o;
    //              document.body.appendChild( div);
    //              }
    //      </script>


    public static void InsertHtmlControl(HtmlControl c, WebBrowser wb)
    {

        // create a HtmlTextWriter;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        // render the control as html
        c.RenderControl(htmlw);


        //invoke the script passing in the html 
        object[] p = new object[1];
        p[0] = (object)sb.ToString();
        wb.Document.InvokeScript("appendHtml", p);

        htmlw.Close();
        htmlw.Dispose();

        sw.Dispose();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCaretPos(ref Point pt);

.....

 HtmlElement newElement = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("<div></div>");
 Point p = new Point();
 GetCaretPos(ref p);
 HtmlElement currentElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(p);
 currentElement.InsertAdjacentElement(HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.AfterBegin, newElement);
```